# PowerBI :How to set graphical template?

Tags: templates, charts, powerbi, graphic

I am new to Power BI, and I need to set a fixed graphical chart to the enterprise.

The chart will be used for all dashboards generated from PowerBI (this chart contains the enterprise Logo, color chart,...).

Actually for the moment I am repeating the settings for every dashboard I create, but I need it to be automatically set as template for example.

Is that possible with Power BI please?

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

There's the ability to add a custom theme from a JSON file. I believe this is still a preview feature you need to enable in the options.

This only does colour palette though. I don't think there's an ability to save the format of a visual as a template. You could suggest it over on the Power BI Ideas forum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test this option.